# Create MEW HD Wallet

Tags: wallets, security

How I understand [MEW](https://www.myetherwallet.com/create-wallet) suppose three cases of wallet:

1. MEW Wallet
2. By Keystore File
3. By Mnemonic Phrase

I know the created wallet by Mnemonic Phrase is kinda HD.

What wallets are HD? And how can I determine the kind of wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- HD Wallets refer to [Hierarchical Deterministic wallets](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki). These wallets can generate multiple "child" keys from a master seed using a derivation algorithm. The seed is generated from a collection of words, usually 12 or 24.
- A keystore file contains an encrypted private key.
- MEW Wallet is the mobile application.

Comment: You say "A keystore file contains an encrypted private key." Do the Keystore file contain only one key? For example, If I use KF then I can use only one PK. Or I can create another KF with another PK. But I can't create two private keys in one KF. For that, I have to use HD. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: @Mr.JE A keystore file contains a single private key, but you can have many keystore files.